# E405 When trying to create an issue using jira-python 0.25

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

I've been using jira-python for some time, but always for queries so far. Now I need to create a new issue from a python script - and it's not working for me.

Whatever I do, I get an E405 (method not allowed error). But it is not - repeat not - a permissions problem.

To try and track this down, I sent the POST command using `curl` manually. No problem, everything worked and the issue was created.

So, I assumed my code was setting up the arguments for `create_issue` incorrectly. I dropped into ipython, enabled pdb, and tried the `create_issue()` call. Sure enough, I got an Exception in the jira-python library. Moved up the stack from `raise_on_error` and it looked like this:

```
    500         url = self._get_url('issue')
    501         r = self._session.post(url, headers={'content-type': 'application/json'}, data=json.dumps(data))
--> 502         raise_on_error(r)
    503 
    504         raw_issue_json = json.loads(r.text)
```

Did a `json.dumps(data)` to recover the actual string being fed in and got:

```
'{"fields": {"issuetype": {"name": "Bug"}, "summary": "RFU", "project": {"key": "TW"}, "components": [{"name": "A Component"}]}}'
```

Which I then cut'n'paste directly as the `--data` parameter to `curl`. And it worked fine.

Which seems to imply that `jira-python` is not working (tried it with 0.25 and 0.18).

Nor is it a python version issue (tried it with pythons 2.7, 3.3, 3.4)

My `create_issue()` call looks like this:

```
j.create_issue(project={'key':'TW'}, issuetype={'name':'Bug'}, summary='RFU', components=[{'name':'A Component'}])
```

All the field values specified are valid (though different than shown here)

WTH am I doing that is so wrong? This functionality can't possibly be broken in the library

I'm working in virtualenv's and here's the output of pip freeze

```
argparse==1.2.1
ipython==2.1.0
jira==0.25
oauthlib==0.6.3
requests==2.3.0
requests-oauthlib==0.4.1
six==1.7.2
tlslite==0.4.6
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Which was set up with a simple `pip install ipython jira` command

BTW, if I fetch an existing issue and then call `issue.update()` with suitable params, it works fine.

One other item: I'm running Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: What version of JIRA?

Comment: Jira version is 6.2.2

Comment: Just as an interesting side-note. According to  https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/6.2.2/ (the rest API docs), none of the rest API's documents being able to produce an E405 - But I suspect it's a generic error (like a 404)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got it working - it was down to some internal network vagaries.

Our internal JIRA server had an expired certificate. So they switched it from https to http.

I created my jira instance with `'server':'https://...'` and `'verify':False` to bypass the certificate error. jira-python presumably just connected via http and used that for all the queries.

But when it came time to POST to the site we got a problem with the https vs http issue.

Switching to `'server':'http://...'` and dropping the `'verify'` option got it working.

I found a  hint [here](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/121063/jira-api-returns-405-error)